Failed to find a supported hardware rendering device.Verify that DirectX is properly installed and that you have the latest drivers for your system
I am attempting to install Age of Empires IV on Linux (Gold Status on ProtonDB).
Age of Empires IV
Failed to find a supported hardware rendering device. Ensure that your system meets the minimum requirements for Age of Empires IV. Verify that DirectX is properly installed and that you have the latest drivers for your system.
OK
Don't show this message for [ 1 ] days

I never play video games and to be fully honest am uncertain what this means.
What can I do to verify DirectX is installed? How do I install it?
My installation was made utilizing the Flathub version of Steam.
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.



You may want to try enabling Proton Experimental...

Now... 4 days ago you asked this question and mentioned a Raspberry Pi. Is it the same system? If so then bad news: It doesn't work in ARM.

@ChanganAuto No, it is on an x230 ThinkPad.
Another reason for the error (that I am now realizing) is the age of the machine. I have all the necessary specs (I5, intel GPU, etc.) but they models within my machine are somewhat old in comparison to recent contributions.

@ChanganAuto I will attempt this

Probably a waste of time. If the machine doesn't support the required DirectX version in native Windows, it can't possible work emulated.
